# iMacros script: Save the content of the modified EXTRACTed link without using TAG or URL command

Tags: imacros

Does iMacros support save the content of the extracted url directly? I need because I will try for a replaced url.

```
'--- Get the URL from the image ---
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=CLASS:cover EXTRACT=HREF

'--- Replace it ---
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/resolution=500/g, 'resolution=100');")

'--- Downlad image without "URL GOTO {{!EXTRACT}}" command ---
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=cover FILE=image.jpg
??? CONTENT=EVENT:SAVEITEM
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to solve your issue with the help of pseudo-URL:

```
URL GOTO=javascript:{document.querySelector("img[class='cover']").src=document.querySelector("img[class='cover']").src.replace(/resolution=500/g,'resolution=100');}
WAIT SECONDS=1
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=cover FILE=image.jpg
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=CLASS:cover CONTENT=EVENT:SAVEITEM
```

Comment: Thank you @Shugar. It didn't work but anyway did you plan to use `URL GOTO`? Will `URL GOTO` open new page? If yes, my request is different. My aim is downloading without revisit or reopen. I think there 2 methods can be: 1st: Modify the content of webpage directly without extract, then download. 2nd Extract the content, modify, and download directly. Are they possible with iMacros?

Comment: Well, I did suggest the 1st method mentioned by you. Try my code under 'iMacros for Chrome' or 'iMacros for Firefox' (v. 8.9.7 or lower). BTW, the 2nd way is possible for Firefox as well.